# Create new dataframe based on distinct combinations of column values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ['Date1', 'Date1', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date2', 'Date2', 'Date3', 'Date3', 'Date3', 'Date4', 'Date4', 'Date4'], 
     'col2': ['Date2', 'Date3', 'Date4', 'Date1', 'Date3', 'Date4', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date4', 'Date1', 'Date2', 'Date3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

[image]

How do I get a unique list of combinations of the values in the columns, like this?

[image]

I have tried nested for loops using df.itertuples() and df.drop() and am just getting lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort the `col1`/`col2` and then drop duplicates:

```py
df["tmp"] = df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(sorted, axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset="tmp").drop(columns="tmp")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    col1   col2
0  Date1  Date2
1  Date1  Date3
2  Date1  Date4
4  Date2  Date3
5  Date2  Date4
8  Date3  Date4
```

Comment: This returns an error `unhashable type: 'list'`  when running the second line.

Comment: @EthanT What value types do you have in the columns? Just strings or something else?

Comment: Just strings.  I am copying and pasting the code to create the date and also then the code you provided, this is what is happening. Strange thing is, it works on my local machine fine, just not the remote server I am trying to run it on.

Comment: @EthanT Check the pandas versions. If you have only strings in columns, it should work.

Comment: That is very interesting.  If I do `df.dtypes`, it shows the data type for each column as an object.  I then have to convert each column, including the `"tmp" `column using `.astype('string')` and then it works.  On my local machine, it works without conversion.

Comment: Replace `sorted` with `frozenset`.

Comment: @Corralien This could work for this case (two columns), but for three and more not (consider rows `data1 data1 data2` and `data1 data2 data2`)

Comment: Yes indeed, it doesn't work for more than 2 columns.